# singleInstance launch mode: why is onCreate called after activity is brought to front?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I launch main activity, change some settings in UI, press back button and then reopen the activity. `onCreate()` is called again and activity is back to default state. Why is this?

I would expect only `onResume()` to be called since I have this in Manifest:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Comment: Pressing the back button destroys the activity currently in front so when you open it is should really call onCreate.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `moveTaskToBack(true);` in `onBackPressed()` to make your current activity hide instead of destroying, so you can reopen it again

```
@Override
public void onBackPresses(){
   moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

Comment: I didn"t know this method! but you still have to keep in mind that the activity can be destroyed by the system, so don't rely on the fact that it's not destroyed

Answer (score 1):

> I launch main activity, change some settings in UI, press back button and then reopen the activity. onCreate() is called again and activity is back to default state. Why is this?

This is expected behavior of activity life cycle. When you press back button then activity get destroyed, it will start from `onCreate` method.

[image]

Comment: My bad. I think I'll need to override `onBackPressed()` and ask if user really wants to exit. Otherwise he should use Home button.

Comment: @Primož'c0dehunter'Kralj Yep. You can ask to user if (s)he want to go back then you have to override `onBackPressed`

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you press back, it destroyes the activity. 
I think that what you want is to keep the state when you come back to this activity, not really to have one instance of it. So you should save the information you need and then restore them in onCreate.

Single instance only means (if I remember it well) that if you launch multiple activities without finishing them, the ones that have singleInstance will go back to front when you will call startActivity() and will not call onCreate. But this means you can't have this behavior by pressing back.
Maybe you can override onBackPressed and start another activity (the one you should go back to) instead of calling super.onBackPressed(). this should do what you want but if think it will be kind of difficult to manage.

By the way remember that Activities might be killed by the system itself, so you should not rely on the fact that your activity as not been killed